# Camel commands removed in Karaf console when uninstalling feature

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I'm using Apache ServiceMix 6.1.0, with :

- Karaf 3.0.5
- Camel 2.16.1

The issue I'm facing is that when I uninstall a personal feature from ServiceMix, Camel commands in Karaf console (e.g. `route-list`) are also removed.

Steps :

- Drop `feature.xml`  in `/deploy` of ServiceMix.

Feature file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.1" name="my.feature">
    <feature name="my.feature" version="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" description="my.feature">
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.ws.commons.axiom/axiom-api/1.2.15</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-activation_1.1_spec/1.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:jaxen/jaxen/1.1.6</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec/1.0.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.james/apache-mime4j-core/0.7.2</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.apache.ws.commons.axiom/axiom-impl/1.2.15</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.2.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.google.guava/guava/18.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-io/commons-io/2.3</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:xml-resolver/xml-resolver/1.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.7</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

- Install feature via Karaf console: `feature:install my.feature`
- Result of `bundle:list | grep -i camel` :

> 136 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             | camel-core
>   137 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             |
>   camel-catalog
>   139 | Active |  50 |
>   2.16.1                             | camel-jms
>   140 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             | camel-spring
>   141 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             |
>   camel-blueprint
>   142 | Active |  50 |
>   5.12.1                             | activemq-camel
>   144 | Active |  50 | 6.1.0                              | Apache
>   ServiceMix :: ActiveMQ :: Camel
>   147 | Active |  80 | 2.16.1  | camelcommands-core
>   148 | Active |  80 |
>   2.16.1                             | camel-karaf-commands
>   234 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             |
>   camel-cxf-transport
>   235 | Active |  50 |
>   2.16.1                             | camel-cxf

- Remove feature from `/deploy` folder
- Result of `bundle:list | grep - i camel`

> 136 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             | camel-core
>   137 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             |
>   camel-catalog
>   139 | Active |  50 |
>   2.16.1                             | camel-jms
>   140 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             | camel-spring
>   141 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             |
>   camel-blueprint
>   142 | Active |  50 |
>   5.12.1                             | activemq-camel
>   144 | Active |  50 | 6.1.0                              | Apache
>   ServiceMix :: ActiveMQ :: Camel
>   234 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1
>   | camel-cxf-transport                             235 | Active |  50 |
>   2.16.1                             | camel-cxf

We can see that **camel-commands-core** and **camel-karaf-commands** bundles have also been removed.

- Logs :

servicemix.log :

```
2016-03-04 10:11:54,164 | INFO  | l for user karaf | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 20 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 3.0.5 | Installing feature my.feature 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-04 10:11:54,165 | WARN  | l for user karaf | AetherBasedResolver              | 3 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | interval1: null, interval2: daily
2016-03-04 10:11:54,165 | WARN  | l for user karaf | AetherBasedResolver              | 3 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | interval1: null, interval2: daily
2016-03-04 10:11:54,165 | WARN  | l for user karaf | AetherBasedResolver              | 3 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | interval1: daily, interval2: daily
2016-03-04 10:11:54,165 | WARN  | l for user karaf | AetherBasedResolver              | 3 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | interval1: daily, interval2: daily
2016-03-04 10:11:54,165 | WARN  | l for user karaf | AetherBasedResolver              | 3 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | interval1: daily, interval2: daily
2016-03-04 10:11:54,165 | WARN  | l for user karaf | AetherBasedResolver              | 3 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | interval1: daily, interval2: daily
...
2016-03-04 10:11:54,794 | INFO  | l for user karaf | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 20 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 3.0.5 | Found installed feature camel-core-condition-shell_0_0_0 2.16.1
2016-03-04 10:15:28,584 | INFO  | mix-6.1.0/deploy | fileinstall                      | 7 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.5.0 | Uninstalling bundle 272 (feature.xml)
2016-03-04 10:15:56,846 | INFO  | lixDispatchQueue | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 20 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 3.0.5 | Uninstalling feature my.feature 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-04 10:15:56,849 | INFO  | lixDispatchQueue | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 20 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 3.0.5 | Uninstalling feature camel-core-condition-shell_0_0_0 2.16.1
2016-03-04 10:15:56,875 | INFO  | lixDispatchQueue | BlueprintExtender                | 15 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.4 | Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.camel.karaf.camel-karaf-commands/2.16.1
```

Would you know why these camel bundles are removed ?